# $C_0^\infty(\overline \Omega)$ is dense in $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, book-recommendation

I've been looking for a while in different Functional Analysis books such as Luc Tartar, Jean Pierre Aubin and Brezis but couldn't find the proof of the density of $C_0^\infty(\overline \Omega)$ in $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with Lipschitz boundary $\Gamma:=\partial \Omega$. Can you recommend me a good source to check it?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $H( $ div ; $\Omega)$?

Comment: $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega) := \{ v \in [L^2(\Omega)]^n \mid \operatorname{div} v \in L^2(\Omega) \}$.

Comment: $n$ is the dimension of the space. I mean, $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$? I don't think $C_{0}^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense in $H(div;\Omega)$. See here for why: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201586/is-c-0-infty-omega-cap-hm-p-omega-dense-in-hm-p-omega?rq=1

Comment: Absolutely sure. Notice that we are talking about $\overline \Omega$ and not about $\Omega$.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides: Mybe I'm confusing notation, but if $C_0^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ is the space of smooth functions in $\bar{\Omega}$ that vanish at the boundary then the result is not true: The function $f(x)=(1,\ldots, 1)$ lies in $H(div,\Omega)$ but it can't be approximated in this space since functions in $H(div,\Omega)$ admit a normal trace $u\cdot \nu$ (here $\nu$ is the normal to $\partial\Omega$), but normal traces for functions in $C_0^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ are all zero. Could you write the explicit definition of $C_0^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$?